# Create Batch script to copy specific files from one folder to another

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I am attempting to copy specific files from one folder to another.  The files in the source folder may have a names like:

```
1FT_DINRM_TASCAM_pt5GAL_TCL_cpl.wav
1FT_DINRM_TASCAM_pt5GAL_TCL_lcpl.wav
1FT_DINRM_TASCAM_pt5GAL_TCL.wav
```

I just want to copy the files that have `cpl` and `lcpl` in their names.

I am not sure how to implement this in the batch script that is currently at this stage:

```
mkdir Modified_originalClip
set "source=G:\Personal Data\Unclipped"
set "destination=G:\Personal Data\Modified_originalClip"
robocopy "%source%" "%destination%" /mov /minage:%X%
```

Any help to copy the specific files in the Windows 10 environment will be sincerely appreciated!

Comment: Simply use `@%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "G:\Personal Data\Unclipped" "G:\Personal Data\Modified_originalClip" *cpl*.wav /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS /R:3 /W:10`. __ROBOCOPY__ creates itself the entire directory tree to specified destination directory if the destination directory does not already exist. Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `robocopy /?` and read the output help.

Comment: @Joe, you were really close to solving this yourself. I would like to point out what it says in the help file for `ROBOCOPY`. **file :: File(s) to copy  (names/wildcards: default is "\*.\*").**