# Create Batch script to copy specific files from one folder to separate folders based on ending of filename

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

This question is building off the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66930889/create-batch-script-to-copy-specific-files-from-one-folder-to-another?noredirect=1#comment118321489_66930889).

The original folder has names like:

```
1FT_DINRM_TASCAM_pt5GAL_TCL_clp.wav
1FT_DINRM_TASCAM_pt5GAL_TCL_lclp.wav
1FT_DINRM_TASCAM_pt5GAL_TCL.wav
```

I want to create 3 separate folders to hold the files with the different ending into individual folders like this:

```
Files with xxx_clp to go into a folder, "Modified_originalClip"
Files with xxx_lclp to go into a folder, "Modified_originalLightClip" and
Files with none of the above endings, to go into a folder, "Modified_originalNoClip"
```

This is the code I came up with that is located in the same batch file:

```
@%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "G:\DataSet\PlasticBagPops\Personal Data\NSULabGlass\Modified" "G:\DataSet\PlasticBagPops\Personal Data\NSULabGlass\Modified_originalNoClip" *L.wav /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS /R:3 /W:10

@%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "G:\DataSet\PlasticBagPops\Personal Data\NSULabGlass\Modified" "G:\DataSet\PlasticBagPops\Personal Data\NSULabGlass\Modified_originalClip" *_clp.wav /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS /R:3 /W:10

@%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "G:\DataSet\PlasticBagPops\Personal Data\NSULabGlass\Modified" "G:\DataSet\PlasticBagPops\Personal Data\NSULabGlass\Modified_originalLightClip" *_lclp.wav /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS /R:3 /W:10
```

Is it possible to make the path dynamic instead of hard coded?  That is, to carry out this operation from where the batch file is located.  If the batch file is located as follows:

```
| Original
| Modified_originalClip
     |1FT_DINRM_TASCAM_pt5GAL_TCL_clp.wav
| Modified_originalLightClip
     |1FT_DINRM_TASCAM_pt5GAL_TCL_lclp.wav
| Modified_originalNoClip
     |1FT_DINRM_TASCAM_pt5GAL_TCL.wav
| filetofolder.bat
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want to replace `"G:\DataSet\PlasticBagPops\Personal Data\NSULabGlass\Modified"` with `the folder where my batch file is stored`, it's easy:`robocopy "%~dp0" "dp0Modified_originalNoClip" *L.wav <etc>` If that's not what you want, please be more specific.

Comment: There are plenty of questions and answers on StackOverFlow and the Internet for that matter that discuss, Absolute Path, Relative Path and Script Path.  These are core principles you need to understand in any programming language as your program needs to know what it's current working directory is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use the following batch file which can be stored in the folders:

```
G:\DataSet\PlasticBagPops\Personal Data\NSULabGlass
G:\DataSet\PlasticBagPops\Personal Data\NSULabGlass\Modified
```

The batch file code is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if exist "%~dp0*.wav" (
    for %%I in ("%~dp0.") do (
        set "SourceFolder=%%~fI"
        set "TargetFolder=%%~fI_original"
    )
) else if exist "%~dp0Modified\*.wav" (
    set "SourceFolder=%~dp0Modified"
    set "TargetFolder=%~dp0Modified_original"
) else (
    echo(
    echo ERROR: Cannot find a *.wav file in the folders:
    echo        "%~dp0"
    echo        "%~dp0Modified\"
    echo(
    pause
    goto EndBatch
)

if exist "%SourceFolder%\*_lclp.wav" %SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%SourceFolder%" "%TargetFolder%LightClip" *_lclp.wav /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS /R:3 /W:10
if exist "%SourceFolder%\*_clp.wav" %SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%SourceFolder%" "%TargetFolder%Clip" *_clp.wav /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS /R:3 /W:10
if exist "%SourceFolder%\*L.wav" %SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%SourceFolder%" "%TargetFolder%NoClip" *L.wav /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS /R:3 /W:10

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

The expression `%~dp0` references the drive and path of argument 0 which expands always to full path of currently processed batch file ending with a backslash. So for the two examples above `%~dp0` is one of the following two folder paths:

```
G:\DataSet\PlasticBagPops\Personal Data\NSULabGlass\
G:\DataSet\PlasticBagPops\Personal Data\NSULabGlass\Modified\
```

The batch file checks first if there is at least one `.wav` directory entry (hopefully a file and not a directory of which name ends with `.wav`) in the directory of the batch file. This is the case for batch file being stored in the directory `G:\DataSet\PlasticBagPops\Personal Data\NSULabGlass\Modified`.

**ROBOCOPY** has like **REG** an unusual parsing of argument strings. These two Windows commands interpret a backslash `\` left to one more backslash `\` or a double quote `"` as an escape character for the backslash respectively the double quote while a backslash left to any other character is interpreted as literal character backslash. This special argument parsing makes sense for the command **REG** as it is often necessary to define a data string containing double quotes, but it does not really make sense in my opinion for command **ROBOCOPY** as it is impossible that a folder path or a file name contains a double quote character. However, that special argument parsing means that neither the source folder path assigned to environment variable `SourceFolder` nor the target folder path assigned to environment variable `TargetFolder` should end with a backslash as this backslash would be interpreted as escape character for `"` and **ROBOCOPY** would interpret everything right to `"` terminating the source/target folder path up to next `"` without a backslash left to it as part of the source respectively target folder path although a folder path cannot contain a double quote character.

For that reason the command **FOR** is used to get the full path of the batch file without a backslash appended assigned to environment variable `SourceFolder`. The dot after `%~dp0` means current directory. The usage of `%%~fI` forces command **FOR** to access the file system and this results in determining the absolute path of the folder path with relative path part `.` for current directory at end of the folder path.

The target folder path assigned to environment variable `TargetFolder` is in this case the batch file path without backslash at end, but with `_original` appended. So the batch file could be stored also in a folder with path `C:\Temp\MyWaves` containing one or more `.wav` files in which case the target folder path would be `C:\Temp\MyWaves_original`.

But if the folder containing the batch file does not contain any `.wav` file (directory entry), the batch file checks next if there is in batch file folder a subfolder `Modified` containing at least one `.wav` file. That condition is true if the batch file is stored in folder `G:\DataSet\PlasticBagPops\Personal Data\NSULabGlass`.

If there is no `.wav` file in folder of the batch file and also not in a subfolder `Modified` of the batch file folder, the batch file outputs an appropriate error message, pause the batch file execution until the user pressed a key and next jumps to a label resulting in exiting the batch file processing without doing anything at all.

The next three **IF** conditions check first if there is at least one file matching the wildcard pattern in source folder before running the command **ROBOCOPY** to move the files matching the wildcard pattern.

The order of the three **IF** conditions with **ROBOCOPY** execution on condition being true could be very important depending on the wildcard patterns.

**ROBOCOPY** creates the entire target folder tree automatically on not already existing. So it is not necessary to explicitly create the three target folders using either **MD** or **MKDIR**.

The batch file ends with restoring the execution environment defined outside of the batch file.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.
https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/

- `call /?` ... explains how batch file arguments can be referenced from within a batch file as used here to reference with `%~dp0` the full path of the batch file.
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `robocopy /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`